# what is the serializability graph of this?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

I try to figure out a question, however I do not how to solve it, I am unannounced most of the terms in the question. Here is the question:

> Three transactions; T1, T2 and T3 and schedule program s1 are given
>   below. Please draw the precedence or serializability graph of the s1
>   and specify the serializability of the schedule S1. If possible, write
>   at least one serial schedule. r ==> read, w ==> write
>
> T1: r1(X);r1(Z);w1(X);
>
> T2: r2(Z);r2(Y);w2(Z);w2(Y);
>
> T3: r3(X);r3(Y);w3(Y);
>
> S1: r1(X);r2(Z);r1(Z);r3(Y);r3(Y);w1(X);w3(Y);r2(Y);w2(Z);w2(Y);

I do not have any idea about how to solve this question, I need a detailed description. In which resource should I look for? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various ways to test for serializability. *The Objective of serializability is to find nonserial schedules that allow transactions to execute concurrently without interfering with one another.*

First we do a **Conflict-Equivalent Test**. This will tell us whether the schedule is serializable.

To do this, we must define some rules (i & j are 2 transactions, R=Read, W=Write).

We cannot Swap the order of actions if equivalent to:

```
1. Ri(x), Wi(y) - Conflicts 
2. Wi(x), Wj(x) - Conflicts
3. Ri(x), Wj(x) - Conflicts 
4. Wi(x), Rj(x) - Conflicts
```

But these are perfectly valid:

```
R1(x), Rj(y) - No conflict (2 reads never conflict)
Ri(x), Wj(y) - No conflict (working on different items)
Wi(x), Rj(y) - No conflict (same as above)
Wi(x), Wj(y) - No conflict (same as above)
```

So applying the rules above we can derive this (using excel for simplicity):

[image]

From the result, we can clearly see with managed to derive a serial-relation (i.e. The schedule you have above, can be split into `S(T1, T3, T2)`.

Now that we have a serializable schedule and we have the serial schedule, we now do the **Conflict-Serialazabile test:**

Simplest way to do this, using the same rules as the **conflict-equivalent test**, look for any combinations which would conflict.

```
r1(x); r2(z); r1(z); r3(y); r3(y); w1(x); w3(y); r2(y); w2(z); w2(y);
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              r1(z)                                     w2(z)
                            r3(y)                              w2(y)
                                          w3(y)  r2(y)
                                          w3(y)                w2(y)
```

Using the rules above, we end up with a table like above (e.g. we know reading `z` from one transaction and then writing `z` from another transaction will cause a conflict (look at rule 3).

Given the table, from left to right, we can create a precedence graph with these conditions:

```
T1 -> T2
T3 -> T2 (only 1 arrow per combination)
```

Thus we end up with a graph looking like this:

[image]

From the graph, since there it's acyclic (no cycle) we can conclude the schedule is conflict-serializable. Furthermore, since its also view-serializable (since every schedule that's conflict-s is also view-s). We could test the view-s to prove this, but it's rather complicated.

Regarding sources to learn this material, I recommend:

*"Database Systems: A practical Approach To design, implementation and management: International Edition"* by Thomas Connolly; Carolyn Begg - (It is rather expensive so I suggest looking for a cheaper, pdf copy)

Good luck!

**Update**
I've developed [a little tool](https://github.com/gudthing/Serializability) which will do all of the above for you (including graph). It's pretty simple to use, I've also added some examples.

Comment: How can I learn much about that issue? In which book, which words shall I write to google?

Comment: @tsozgen I will get back to you. I have a feeling I've made a mistake in my workings so don't accept my answer (I will edit it when I get a chance in next few days)

Comment: I will check. Thank you for your efforts. How can I get detailed information about the topic? What was your sources?

Comment: @tsozgen no problem, sorry I took so long to get back to you. I have checked this particular question with my lecturer, and she confirmed it was correct. If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to accept. Good luck :)